# Weird behavior with LayoutInflater.inflate() method

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater

I was trying to implement a simple list using a linearLayout and a scrollview so the idea was to basically have a List of models and inflate the item Layouts manually .. populate them with data and then add to the LinearLayout which is fine in theory but when I do it this way:

```
//for (item : List) addModelToView(item)
private fun addModelToView(model: Model) {
    val linearLayout = binding.linearContainer
    val item = activity?.layoutInflater?.inflate(R.layout.model_layout,linearLayout, true)
    item?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView10)?.text = model.name
    item?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView11)?.text = model.company
    item?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView12)?.text = model.size.toString()
}
```

but doing it this way only displays the **Last** item correctly while the rest of the items are there but with the default values of the xml layout .. like the following

[image]

So what exactly am I missing here? I tried inflating the item layouts manually and using `ViewGroup.addView()` method with `LayoutParams` and it worked just fine but I don't see how the two approaches are different

Comment: Sounds like reinventing the wheel. Wouldn't it be better to use the RecyclerView?

Comment: I'm  just trying new things and in the process see how different APIs work. Like here I'm curious to know how the LayoutInflater Operated differently from what I had expected it to do and why that's the case

Comment: Check return value of [`layoutInflater.inflate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater#inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)) - it's linear layout, not the newly created view.

Comment: @Pawel ok that could be it but I still don't see it the sequence is gonna be .. Empty container -> inflate() -> Container with one populated item -> inflate() -> ?? .. is the return gonna be that same container with the previous items but defaulted out? why didn't they retain the state from the previous inflation?

Comment: @gemy845 the implication is "item == linearlayout" so you do "linearlayout.findviewbyId(...)". That means regardless of how many times you do the inflation you will always get and update views from the first "item".

Comment: @Pawel ok I got it now! Would you mind Answering below so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is return value of [`layoutInflater.inflate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater#inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)).

When you provide root and set `attachToRoot` to true it returns the root itself - not the newly created view. This causes your `view.findViewById` to essentially be `linearLayout.findViewById` and that will always find and return the first set of views, regardless of haw many times you've performed the inflation.